# Intermittent ec2ApiErrCount in EKS CNI Metrics Helper

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, cni

I've noticed that the `ec2ApiErrCount` metric sometimes reports non-zero values

To investigate potential EC2 API errors, I enabled CloudTrail management events.
However, I didn't find any corresponding EC2 API error logs in CloudTrail.

here is my query snippet:

```
fields @timestamp, @log, eventName
| filter eventSource like "ec2.amazonaws.com"
| filter userAgent like "amazon-vpc-cni"
| sort @timestamp desc
```

Are there other factors or logs that I should check to understand the discrepancy between the ec2ApiErrCount metric and CloudTrail logs?

What could be causing `ec2ApiErrCount` to report non-zero values ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the log insight query snippet for filtering error EC2 API calls from VPC CNI:

```
fields @timestamp, userAgent, eventName
| filter not isempty(errorCode)
| filter eventSource like "ec2.amazonaws.com"
| filter userAgent like "amazon-vpc-cni"
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 100
```

I've noticed that there are some `DeleteNetworkInterface` error like "Network interface 'eni-xxxx' is currently in use."

However, this error, which is common, is handled by a retry loop.